# Getting Error : ld: file is universal (2 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7 slice

Tags: ios, armv7

I am new to iOS developing. When I am running the app in device I got below error :

```
ld: file is universal (2 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7 slice: /Users/username/Projects/Project-name/tesseract-ocr/outdir/libtesseract_api.a for architecture armv7
```

I am using `xcode 4.6`.

Thanks in Advance.